# I need to prevent line break on enter key pressed until a certain character length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to prevent line break on enter key pressed but it needs to make at least some new para depending on the size of the text area. I tried with this but it just prevent the enter key press. I need to create new line until the height of the text area then if someone press enter they are not then be able to create new line..

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text"  class="Post_Description_Text">Some Text here</textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
.Post_Description_Text{ 
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".Post_Description_Text").keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
  }
});
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var rowN=1;
 $(".Post_Description_Text").keydown(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey && rowN<5)
  {
  e.preventDefault();
    var s = $(this).val();
       $(this).val(s+"\n"+"\t");
       ++rowN;
       }
       else
       return false;
      
 });
```

```css
.Post_Description_Text{ 
    width:400px;
    height:80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text"  class="Post_Description_Text" rows="5">Some</textarea>
```

Using the above code you can make a new para when user press enter key and also restrict user to enter lines using rows and javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the JavaScript code that does same

```
document.getElementById('comment_text').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/yq1bLaaz/